# VB.NET Showing data in database to Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm getting the following error when i want to show the data in database to `datagridview`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connect()
    Try
        strsql = "select * from tbInfo"
        cmd.CommandText = strsql
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(strsql, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "tbInfo")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

and this is the module:

```
Sub connect()
    strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|datadirectory|\dbExam1.accdb"
    conn = New OleDbConnection(strcon)
    conn.Open()

    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        MsgBox("CONNETED!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the lines .Try, Catch, MessageBox, End Try and Run th code again. On which line is the error - there as several possibilities. Cheers

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Where you create the cmd variable? It is not necessary because you use a DataAdapater.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    connect() 
    Try
    strsql = "select * from tbInfo"
    'comment this line   
    'cmd.CommandText = strsql 
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(strsql, conn) 
    Dim ds As New DataSet() 
    da.Fill(ds, "tbInfo") 
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0) 
    conn.Close() 
    Catch ex As Exception 
    MsgBox(ex.Message) 
    End Try
    End Sub

    Sub connect() 
    strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|datadirectory|\dbExam1.accdb" 
    conn = New OleDbConnection(strcon) 
    conn.Open()

        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            MsgBox("CONNETED!")
        End If
    End Sub
```